# Re using wpf window and c# in base project for using again

Tags: c#, wpf

I am still getting used to working with c# and wpf. I have made a number of smalls apps to do single tasks. To give the same feel to the apps my company uses I use the same logo, colours and layout.I am also developing a project settings class to save the project variables to file using a json file ( I hope ) and a slide out panel to give the user access to the project variables.

It would make sense to save this as a  sort of template / base project so that every time I start a new project I can use this  base project to shortcut the workload   but every time I to do this I get errors. I have read about class library but am not certain if the is correct way forward or should be some sort of template.

Can someone  explain if want I want to do is possible in wpf and what is the correct way forward please. Any questions on here (this site) assumed a bit too much knowledge for me and I can't get my head around the msdn references. So any good links would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, once you have the basic solution template that you want.

File->Export Tenplate.

Create a new Project Template.

Or if you just want to create a reusable theme. Create a class library and put some ResourceDictionaries inside with your styles and templates, etc. Then reference it from each new project and import the resource dictionaries. This solution would probably be easier to maintain over time as you could easily replace the referenced DLL with a new version when you make changes to the common UI theming.

Comment: Thanks I will look into Resource dictionary as it sound like the best practice - cheers